# Ant: How to obtain Java path without invoking path from Main?

Tags: ant

I'm doing plugin development but none of classes will have a main. So without hard coding a path to my java directory how do i go about doing this?

I currently do this hack job

```
<property name="jdk.home.1.6" value="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_22"/>
```

and build upon that.

Comment: may you explain exactly which kind of plugin you're developing and in which environment this plugin should run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have built-in properties in ant: http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/ant/findHomePath.shtml
That mean you can use:

```
<property name="jdk.home.1.6" value="${java.home}"/>
```

HIH

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `System.properties()`

`System.properties()` will return information regarding the current java virtual machine configuration.

- "file.separator"  Character that separates components of a file path. This is "/" on UNIX and "\" on Windows.
- "java.class.path" Path used to find directories and JAR archives containing class files. Elements of the class path are separated by a platform-specific character specified in the path.separator property.
- **"java.home" Installation directory for Java Runtime Environment (JRE)**
- "java.vendor" JRE vendor name
- "java.vendor.url" JRE vendor URL
- "java.version"    JRE version number
- "line.separator"  Sequence used by operating system to separate lines in text files
- "os.arch" Operating system architecture
- "os.name" Operating system name
- "os.version"  Operating system version
- "path.separator"  Path separator character used in java.class.path
- "user.dir"    User working directory
- "user.home"   User home directory
- "user.name"   User account name

Comment: Ahh I wanted a self contained build file (not relaying on other external property files). Is that possible?